# Loading data from USGS National Map server in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, usgs

How can I add data from the USGS National Map server to ArcMap?

Specific goal is to load data and processed products like 3DEP hillshades from the [TNM Download](https://apps.nationalmap.gov/downloader/#/) without having to download it locally, make a hillshade, etc.

I think I need the raster.nationalmap.gov service (http://raster.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services), but I keep getting connection error after a long delay.

I am following the [USGS instructions here](https://www.usgs.gov/media/videos/using-national-map-web-services-arcmap) although I am not certain if this is what I need for 3DEP hillshades.

[image]

Using ArcMap 10.7 on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar question in the ESRI forums [here](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/problem-connecting-to-a-wcs-server-with-arcgis-pro/td-p/595071). The answer by "isburns" on 7/12/2021 is exactly what I needed. Here's a summary:

The USGS has a [video tutorial](https://www.usgs.gov/media/videos/lesson-10f-national-map-3dep-elevation-web-service-arcmap) for adding the 3DEP service to ArcMap. Key point is to use "Add ArcGIS Server" and this URL: https://elevation.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/3DEPElevation/ImageServer/WCSServer

The video also shows how to access the processed products (right click on 3DEPElevation layer after you add it to your map; click Properties; then Processing Templates tab).

Comment: Any documentation or video on using web services from 2015 is suspect in terms of service URLs.  Although *caveat utilitor* should apply given the age of the video, shame on USGS for leaving training cruft out on the web to confuse users.